# javascript Unexpected identifier with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the following function

```
<script type="text/javascript">function downloadfunction(keyword){_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Class1','Download',keyword])}</script>
```

which fires when an user clicks an submit box

```
type="submit" onClick = "downloadfunction(Where am I Wearing: A Global Tour to the Countries, Factories, and People That Make Our Clothes)
```

however when this fires I get the following error

Unexpected identifier

any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

In your second code snippet you appear to be missing the second set of double quotes.

The string you're passing also requires quotes.

SHould be more like

```
 type="submit" onclick = "downloadfunction('Where           
 am I Wearing: A Global Tour to the Countries,     
 factories, and People That Make Our Clothes');"
```